# Multiple appSettings section in web.config

Tags: .net, design-patterns, configuration, web-config, appsettings

Is this possible in anyway? For example through having named appSettings sections, or appSettings nested in other named sections.

I want to achieve something like the following:

```
<section name="development">
    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>
</section>

<section name="test">
    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>
</section>


string connectionString 
   = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("test").AppSettings["connectionString"];
```

What is the pattern for this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @lance we have multiple teams using the same app, but they each need their own settings as they all have their own data servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appSetting element supports a "file" attribute, which lets you specify a filename were key/values can be placed.

This lets you *not* share with the team the values you've specified in user.config.

I *think*, if you define a single key in *both* the parent and child config files, the child value will be ignored and the parent value will be respected.

[Further Reading](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555396)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that what you're trying to do is simply apply a different connection string (or manipulate other web.config settings) when deploying to different environments, what you're looking for is [config transforms](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html). This is fastest, easiest and *correct* way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve will not work this way. The "best" (IMHO) technique for this is to create 3 files app(or web).config dev.config and test.config (and perhaps release.config). Then in the solution properties you can execute a pre-build command to copy the appropriate .config file so that it becomes "active" based on the build type, into the app.config (or web.config).

you can learn more about this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983464%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Scott Hanselman has a great article on this approach: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx

**So you need to do this at runtime:**

If you want to get different settings at run time then the approach that will probably work best is to establish a naming convention like:

```
<appSettings>
   <add name="fearofawhackplanet.connectionString" value="your connection string" />
   <add name="cosCallis.connectionString" value="my connection string" />
</appSettings>
```

I trust from there you can see how to manage this at runtime to get the key/values you need.

Comment: unfortunately I need to be able to switch at run time

Answer (score 0):

I found custom sections to be most flexible for that. See "configSections Element (General Settings Schema)" in MSDN.

```
<sampleSection serverInstanceLabel1="alex" setting1="Value1"
               setting2="value two"/>
```

So, in your case you can have sections like:sampleSection,sampleSection1,...